# How to get the homepage url?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a redirect page on Wordpress.  The `PHP` will return back to the website homepage. But I can't get back the home page url.

My php file path `xampp\htdocs\wordpress\return.php`.

And here is my code:

```
       $url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
       header('Refresh: 3;url=' . $url);
       echo get_option('home');
       echo $url;
```

The `$url` is `localhost8080/wordpess/return.php`.
I want to go `url : local:8080/wordpress` from `url : localhost8080/wordpess/return.php`.

How can I get back the url `local:8080/wordpress`?

Thx

Comment: By `localhost8080/wordpess/return.php`, do you actually mean `localhost:8080/wordpress/return.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a built-in function for that: `wp_redirect`([see doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/))

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' ); // first you need to load WordPress libraries if you are in an external file.

wp_redirect( home_url() );

exit; // don't forget to exit after a redirection
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to redirect your page from `localhost:8080/wordpess/return.php` to `localhost:8080/wordpess/` using -

```
$url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
header('Refresh: 3;url=' . $url);
```

What you need to do is change your `$url` variable to the location where you want to redirect, which is -

```
$url = "http://localhost:8080/wordpess/";
header('Refresh: 3; url =' . $url);
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.

**EDIT** -

If you don't want to hard code the URL, you can try the following -

```
$url = "/wordpess";
header("Refresh: 3; url = http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $url);
```

Comment: Ys, I want to redirect the page to `localhost:8080/wordpress`. But I don't want to hardcode the path.

Comment: @Capslock10 I've updated the answer. Hope that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding of your question, you want to go back one level from the current page. This is it?

If so, you can accomplish that by doing some string manipulation as follows:

```php
<?php
    // Given that your current url is in the '$url' var
    $url = 'localhost8080/wordpess/return.php';

    // Find the position of the last forward slash
    $pos = strrpos($url, '/');

    // Get a substring of $url starting at position 0 to $pos 
    // (if you want to include the slash, add 1 to the position)
    $new_url = substr($url, 0, $pos + 1);

    // Then you can have the redirection code using the $new_url variable
    ...
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood. 
Hope it helps. Cheers.